# File get contents Error 405: Method Not Allowed - PHP

Tags: java, php, api, get, file-get-contents

I am using the bellow code to retrieve data from an API:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=CF0D1FA323B4F3FCEF90BA3EE4651CAC\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://webfeeder.cedrofinances.com.br/services/quotes/quote/vale5', false, $context);
```

The above code returns the following error message:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://webfeeder.cedrofinances.com.br/services/quotes/quote/vale5): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed in

The API uses REST (HTTP). The above method is describe as GET on documentation.
I've also tried to use PHP CURL. But the same error message is shown.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://webfeeder.cedrofinances.com.br/services/quotes/quote/vale5",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Cookie: JSESSIONID=CF0D1FA323B4F3FCEF90BA3EE4651CAC"),
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

The API documentation shows the following JAVA code to retrieve this same data:

```
public void getQuote(){
   GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod ("http://webfeeder.cedrofinances.com.br/services/quotes/quote/vale5");
   String result = HttpUtils.get(getMethod);
   System.out.println(resutl);
}
```

Comment: If the API returns "Method not allowed" on GET even though it should allow GET requests to that url, I would start by contacting the API developers.

Comment: Have you checked that the Java version works, documentation can sometimes be incorrect.

Comment: The company offering the service does not provide any support. For the sake of curiosity, I'll post the solution if I solve the problem. Thanks